# How TargetNamespace is different from Namespace

Tags: java, xml, xsd, namespaces

I'm new to xsd and learning about namespaces. Seen maximum all questions, blog etc but no one could help me understand in simple way.

What I have understood so far is that, Namespaces are used to differentiate elements having same names. (Not cleared about targetnamespace)

My understanding to make namespace is below

```
xlmns:foo()="URI" -->Namespace (Its a unique token I would say which is responsible to differentiate elements with this syntax. And this synatx given a name and the criteria of making that name is Prefix:ElementName-->Prefix.
```

I have got one example

```
<foo:tag xmlns:foo="http://me.com/namespaces/foofoo"  
         xmlns:bar="http://me.com/namespaces/foobar"  
         >  

  <foo:head>  
    <foo:title>An example document</foo:title>  
  </foo:head>  

  <bar:body>  
    <bar:e1>a simple document</bar:e1>  
    <bar:e2>  
      Another element  
    </bar:e2>  
  </bar:body>  
</foo:tag>
```

If we want to use multiple namespaces in a xsd then we can declare them once like in above example. Where same prefix is being used for multiple namespaces

```
foo:tag --->xmlns:foo="http://me.com/namespaces/foofoo" 
foo:tag --->xmlns:bar="http://me.com/namespaces/foobar
```

Is it same like in java where in a package we can have multiple classes and each class has its own attributes, in case of xml its elements. Am I correct ? Can anyone help me to understand TargetNamespace ?

Answer (score 1):

The `targetNamespace` is the namespace that is ***going to be assigned to the schema you are creating*** or the namespace that this ***schema is intended to target, or validate***. It is the namespace an instance is going to use to access the types it declares.

For example :

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.bestxml.com/jswbook/po">
...
</schema>
```

In an XML document instance, you declare the namespaces you are going to be using by means of the `xmlns` attribute

```
<purchaseOrder xmlns="http://www.bestxml.com/jswbook/po"
xmlns:addr="http://www.bestxml.com/jwsbook/addr">
  <accountName>Shanita</accountName>
  <accountNumber>123456</accountNumber>
  <addr:street>20 King St</addr:street>
</purchaseOrder>
```